# My nokia s40 phone is not recognised as modem to connect to internet

Tags: internet

What should i do in order to connect to internet using my nokia x2-01 mobile?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

When you first plug in the USB cable, you'll need to select "PC Suite" in the menu that pops up:

[image]

Afterwards, the UMTS connection should appear in the network manager. Click on the networking icon, go to *Edit Connections* → *Mobile Broadband* → *Add* and select your phone.

It's worth a shot. Let me know if this works for you too. :)

Comment: No i have nokia x2-01 phone it wont support this method so i am using wvdial but it have some limitations ubuntu software centre ane and ubuntu one cant detect this connection

Comment: No option for "Ovi Suite" too ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using same mobile phone
i thought it is impossible to connect to internet using this phone untill last week

solution is **wvdial**

1. first install wvdial
2. then open the terminal
3. and give the follwing commands
4. `sudo wvdialconf`
5. `sudo wvdial`
6. If it showing error message
     'gksu gedit /etc/wvdial.conf'
      delete the ' ; ' symbol from user name,password and phone number
   give new username aa
   new password bb
   phone number  *99#